# "Text not allowed in element ul in this context"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

> Text not allowed in element `ul` in this context

I do not understand this error message from the markup validation service and I have been unable to find an answer.

My code is here:

```
<ul class="blog-meta">
    <li><p><a href="" class=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Admin</a></p></li> |
    <li><p><a href="" class=""><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> April 24th,2014</a></p></li> | 
    <li><p><a href="" class=""><i class="fa fa-tags"></i>creative </a>,<a href=""> wordpress</a></p></li> | 
    <li><p><a href="" class=""><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 0 Comments</a></p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this error is due to this  `"|"`  remove it and validate it again.

To solve this write it inside `<li> </li>`

```
<ul class="blog-meta">
    <li><p><a href="" class=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Admin</a> | </p></li> 
</ul>
```